# How to store void* in a stack c++ container

Tags: c++, stack, void-pointers

I'm using a library written in C and the library provides headers which only use void*. The library is used to create a kind of graph, which is stored inside the C data-base. The headers return void* to the nodes in the graph. To create the graph, I need to parse a stack of lets say node names. In parallel to the stack of node names, I need to maintain a stack void* for the nodes. I have something like this:

```
std::stack < void* > nodeStack;   
while (!nodeNameStack.empty()) {  
   // check if nodeNamestack.front() meets some criteria 
   nodeStack.push(C_API_To_Create_Node(nodeNameStack.pop()));

   // Do some processing  
   // check if nodeStack.size() >= 2  
   void *node1 = nodeStack.pop()  
   void *node2 = nodeStack.pop()  
   // Above line issues error saying void value not ignored as it ought to be..
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, as we guarantee nodeStack size is atleast 2. I would appreciate any suggestions to overcome this error..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::stack::pop()` doesn't return the element removed.  You have to read it with `top()` before popping it.

Comment: By way of explanation - as this is a C++ quirk - this was done to allow exception safe code to be written.  Lots written on the issue, e.g. http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/008.htm

Answer (score 1):

2 Things

A) you forgot ;'s after nodeStack.pop().

B) .pop() returns void which is why you are getting the error.  .pop() just removes the element from the stack.  Use .top() to get the element, then .pop() to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The prototype for [stack::pop](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/pop/) is

```
void pop ( );
```

Therefore it does not return anything hence the warning. Perhaps you meant to use [stack::top](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/stack/top/)